# QEMU No 'PCI' bus found for device 'nvme'

Tags: arm, qemu

I'm debuging NVME code with QEMU , QEMU return an err message:No 'PCI' bus found for device 'nvme'.

However,I checked device info,it shows PCI is surportted.

```
root@linux:/home/#qemu-system-arm -machine  vexpress-a9  -device help
Storage devices:
name "am53c974", bus PCI, desc "AMD Am53c974 PCscsi-PCI SCSI adapter"
name "nvme", bus PCI, desc "Non-Volatile Memory Express"
name "nvme-ns", bus nvme-bus, desc "Virtual NVMe namespace"
name "nvme-subsys", desc "Virtual NVMe subsystem"
```

Could anybody give me some tips?

**QEMU command:**

```
root@linux:~/run-kernel/$ qemu-system-arm -nographic -M vexpress-a9 -m 1024M -kernel arch/arm/boot/zImage -append "rdinit=/linuxrc console=ttyAMA0 loglevel=8" -dtb arch/arm/boot/dts/vexpress-v2p-ca9.dtb -device nvme,drive=nvme0,serial=deadbeaf1,num_queues=8 -drive file=disk.qcow2,if=none,id=nvme0
```

**output:**

```
WARNING: Image format was not specified for 'disk.qcow2' and probing guessed raw.
     Automatically detecting the format is dangerous for raw images, write operations on block 0 will be restricted.
     Specify the 'raw' format explicitly to remove the restrictions.
qemu-system-arm: -device nvme,drive=nvme0,serial=deadbeaf1,num_queues=8: No 'PCI' bus found for device 'nvme'
```

**QEMU version:**

```
root@linux:/home/# qemu-system-arm -version
QEMU emulator version 6.0.94
Copyright (c) 2003-2021 Fabrice Bellard and the QEMU Project developers
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to use a PCI device (nvme) on a machine type with no PCI bus (vexpress-a9). This doesn't work, in the same way that trying to plug a real hardware PCI card into a machine with no PCI slots is impossible.

You may be being confused by the '-device help' output: that output lists all devices compiled into that QEMU binary, and does not filter it based on any additional '-machine' option you pass at the same time. So it will always show you everything.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I am searching for a long time on net.Alothough there're many articles,but no articles point this key information.Under your your help,I'm now success run QEMU+x86+Nvme.

That's my command:
`qemu-system-x86_64 -kernel arch/x86_64/boot/bzImage -device nvme,drive=nvme1,serial=deadbeaf -drive file=rootfs.ext2,if=ide,format=raw,id=nvme0 -drive file=disk.qcow2,if=none,id=nvme1 --nographic -append "root=/dev/sda console=ttyS0"`

And that's the start up info:
`[    2.440920] nvme nvme0: 1/0/0 default/read/poll queues'
[    2.499027] scsi 0:0:0:0: Di`

Thanks again!